# Calculate the De Rham Cohomology of de solid ball with out a solid totus inside.

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute the Rham Cohomology groups of $ \overline B_1(0) \; / \; T_\epsilon$: The solid ball of radio 1 in $\mathbb{R}^3$ without a little solid Torus inside.

I guess i should use Mayer Vietoris Theorem. I have been trying with different open covers, but i can not find the proper cover.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried a cover with two convex sets, each of which contains a contractible piece of the torus?

Comment: I tried a lot that way with no luck. any way thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: if $B$ is the ball, then consider the covering of $B$ which by the complement of the torus in $B$ and the torus (after enlarging these sets a bit so that they become open)

Comment: This is probably not what you were expecting. Initially, one tends to think that "using M/V to compute the cohomology of a space" means finding an open cover of that space and blah, and here I am proposing that you consider instead a larger space $B$, and view the space you want to study as one of th two open sets in an open covering of $B$. This trick is very useful.

Comment: In other words, one usually views M-V as a way to study a space by cutting it in two, but it also allows you to study a space by considering as a piece of something bigger.

Comment: I see.. I can now even use Poincare Duality Theorem. Thank you so much! ... I was trying a lot of crazy covers and it is so far easy and elegant!

Comment: Why do you want to use duality for?

Comment: Not sure Yet! but it might help when i write down the Mayer Vietories sequence with the term $H^3_{DR} (B_1) $  ?

Comment: I suggest that instead of guessing what *might* help you write down the long exact sequence of M-V for the covering of $B$ I proposed, and look at it. Decide which cohomology spaces appering in it you know and what it tells you.

Comment: You accepted my answer before even writing the MV sequence I proposed, it seems. You shouldn't. You don't even know if my hint does help or not!

Comment: well i am writing it down right now, I guessed it works at least gives me opens on which i can calculate their cohomology groups, but your right! ... I should check  answers carefully before accepting an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49532/discussion-between-alicia-basilio-and-mariano-suarez-alvarez).